# deploying Nestjs api to Heroku

Tags: typescript, heroku, nestjs

when I deploy Nestjs rest api to heroku I don't get any errors but It gets stuck in a loop for over half an hour before I ended the process manually

[screenshot of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad0Pe.png)

it goes on non-stop

Procfile

```
web: npm run start:prod
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "rest-api",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.13.1"
  },
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "start":"node dist/src/main.js",
    "prestart:prod": "npm install",
    "start:dist": "node dist/main.js",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main.js",
    "postinstall": "npm run prestart:prod",
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^7.1.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^7.1.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.4.2",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.3.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.12.2",
    "config": "^3.3.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "pg": "^8.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.7",
    "@types/jest": "25.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "3.0.2",
    "eslint": "7.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "jest": "26.0.1",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "26.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const serverConfig = config.get('server')
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  const port = process.env.Port|| 3000
  await app.listen(port);
}
bootstrap();
```

any ideas how to fix this ?
I've tried adding some scripts like
"heroku-postbuild": "echo Skip builds on Heroku"
but also didn't work !

**Edit**

the problem has been solved , it was because I used a variable in config.yml file that for some reason heroku kept rejecting !

Answer (score 1):

Your config of the postinstall script is incorrect in the `package.json`

```
"postinstall": "npm run prestart:prod",
"prestart:prod": "npm install",
```

What it does is it triggers the `npm install` all over again.
On heroku running install triggers postinstall after it's finished, that includes manually running `npm install` through a command.

So you run install, which triggers postinstall which triggers another install and so on and so forth.

I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish with that script, but since it does not really do anything i suggest you simply remove it from package.json.

Comment: I removed it still not working I get ```at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=api-prod-nest.herokuapp.com request_id=40cef3c1-bf44-4cf5-b424-29f2108ecaf4 fwd="77.31.44.244" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https``` , I was following : https://www.joshmorony.com/deploying-a-production-nestjs-server-on-heroku/ but nothing is working

Comment: this seems like an issue unrelated to the question you've asked and should probably be separate question

Comment: @Ruqayya I think that in `main.ts` you should have `PORT` and not `Port` as [heroku's docs say](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles#web-servers)

Comment: @NatanDeitch That was actually it with another error , thank you